# How to flatten tables using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I've this query:

```
var usersByBranch = (from u in _db.VRT_User
                             join urb in _db.VRT_UserRoleBranch on u.UserId equals urb.UserId
                             join r in _db.VRT_Role on urb.RoleId equals r.RoleId
                             where branches.Contains(urb.BranchId)
                             select new UserRoleBranchModel
                             {
                                 UserId = u.UserId,
                                 BranchId = urb.BranchId,
                                 RoleId = urb.RoleId,
                                 RoleName = r.RoleName
                             });
```

In this query, for the same userId, the roleId (1-4) and RoleName with the same BranchId are returned separately.

I'd like to flatten the rows, so that a row with the same userId contains all the RoleId and RoleName within the same BranchId.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by contains, but you can't use the same `UserRoleBranchModel` to hold multiple roles, so an anonymous object will do the job:

```
var usersByBranch = (from u in _db.VRT_User
                     join urb in _db.VRT_UserRoleBranch on u.UserId equals urb.UserId
                     join r in _db.VRT_Role on urb.RoleId equals r.RoleId
                     where branches.Contains(urb.BranchId)
                     group r by new { urb.UserId, urb.BranchId } into rg
                     select new {
                         UserId = rg.Key.UserId,
                         BranchId = rg.Key.BranchId,
                         Roles = rg.Select(r => r)
                     });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var usersByBranch = (from u in _db.VRT_User
                             join urb in _db.VRT_UserRoleBranch on u.UserId equals urb.UserId
                             join r in _db.VRT_Role on urb.RoleId equals r.RoleId
                             where branches.Contains(urb.BranchId)
group u by u.UserId into g
                             select new UserRoleBranchModel
                             {
                                 UserId = g.Key,
                                 BranchId = g.First().BranchId,
                                 RoleId = g.First().RoleId,
                                 RoleName = g.First()RoleName
                             });
```

Comment: This will create 3 subqueries. add a `let f = g.First()` before the select

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. There are some { and/or ( missing. Could you please edit the code?

Comment: You should just have `group u by u.UserId into g`.

Comment: The error message now says that VRT_User does not contain g.First().BranchId, g.First().RoleId, and g.First().RoleName. They are in VRT_UserRoleBranch and defined in UserRoleBranchModel.

Comment: I removed g.FirstOrDefault().RoleName and I was able to run the application. Maybe I was not clear enough. The result set is not what I expected. It returned a UserId with a RoleId in the same Branch in one row. What I would like is to get a row with a UserId and all RoleId values that this UserId has in the Branch. For example, userId 1 has RoleId (1-4) in Branch 1. That should be returned as one row, instead of mulitple rows of userId 1 with each roleId.